How to arrange figures in a grid?
I have six pairs of vertically stacked figures. I want to arrange the figures into a 3x2 grid. However, I don't find a way to do it. Since I will receive the required figures from an existing function (here as a dummy, it's stacked_lineplots()), the organization of the figures into the grid MUST be done in a separate function called arrange_stacked_subfigures_into_3x2_grid(figures).
MWE:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def arrange_stacked_subfigures_into_3x2_grid(figures):
    # HOW DO I DO THIS?
    pass

def stacked_lineplots():
    # Create a figure with two vertically stacked subplots
    fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(8, 6))
    
    # Dummy data for the plots
    x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
    y1 = [0, 1, 4, 9, 16]
    y2 = [16, 9, 4, 1, 0]
    
    # Plot the data on the first subplot
    ax1.plot(x, y1, label='y = x^2')
    ax2.plot(x, y2, label='y = 16 - x^2', color='orange')
    
    # Adjust layout to prevent overlap
    plt.tight_layout()
    
    return fig

# To get the figure, simply call the function:
six_figures = []
for i in range(6):
    stacked_sub_figure = stacked_lineplots()
    six_figures.append(stacked_sub_figure)

# Now, you can arrange these figures into a 3x2 grid
grid_figure = arrange_stacked_subfigures_into_3x2_grid(six_figures)

print("Done")

Sample Stacked SUB-figure:

Required final Figure: A grid of 3 columns and 2 rows of the stacked pairs.


Have a look at subfigures https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subfigures.html

One way to do this is by using GridSpec (for the main grid) and GridSpecFromSubplotSpec (for each cell/subplot) :
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

def stacked_lineplots():
    # Create a figure with a specific size
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 12))
    
    # Define an outer GridSpec with 3 rows and 2 columns for the pairs
    outer_gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 3, figure=fig, wspace=0.4, hspace=0.3)  
    
    # Dummy data for the plots
    x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
    y1 = [0, 1, 4, 9, 16]
    y2 = [16, 9, 4, 1, 0]
    
    # Loop over each cell in the outer grid
    for col in range(3):  
        for row in range(2):  
            # Define inner GridSpec for the stacked pair within each outer cell
            inner_gs = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(2, 1, subplot_spec=outer_gs[row, col], hspace=0.2, wspace = 0.1)  
            
            # Top plot of the stacked pair
            ax1 = fig.add_subplot(inner_gs[0])
            ax1.plot(x, y1, label='y = x^2')
            ax1.legend()
            
            # Bottom plot of the stacked pair
            ax2 = fig.add_subplot(inner_gs[1])
            ax2.plot(x, y2, label='y = 16 - x^2', color='orange')
            ax2.legend()
    plt.show()

stacked_lineplots()

Output:

UPDATE: Another way to do this, which some might prefer, is by using subfigures, which would get you the same output as above:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def stacked_lineplots():
    # Create a figure with a specific size
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 12))
    
    # Define the outer grid as 2 rows x 3 columns 
    subfigs = fig.subfigures(2, 3, wspace=0.4, hspace=0.3)  
    
    # Dummy data for the plots
    x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
    y1 = [0, 1, 4, 9, 16]
    y2 = [16, 9, 4, 1, 0]
    
    # Loop over each subfigure in the grid
    for row in range(2):  
        for col in range(3):  
            # Get the current subfigure and create two vertically stacked subplots
            subfig = subfigs[row, col]
            axs = subfig.subplots(2, 1)  
            subfig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.2)  # Adjust the layout within each subfigure for a smaller gap
            
            # Top plot of the stacked pair
            axs[0].plot(x, y1, label='y = x^2')
            axs[0].legend()
            
            # Bottom plot of the stacked pair
            axs[1].plot(x, y2, label='y = 16 - x^2', color='orange')
            axs[1].legend()
    plt.show()

stacked_lineplots()


This is the old way to do this.  Modern Matplotlib has subfigures https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subfigures.html

I'm not sure about the 'Modern' way but I didn't notice any deprecation warning issued by Matplotlib for the gridspec module. Thanks for your suggestion, I updated the answer to include subfigures.

Users should rarely need to directly know about gridspecs.  Subfigures also allow multiple suptitles and supy/xlabels
